# Error while running react using npm start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am learning react and have gotten the following error.

````
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! learningreact@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the learningreact@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!```
````

Comment: Delete ```node_modules``` folder and ```package-lock.json``` file and run ```npm install```. Fixes almost all npm related issues instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your package-lock.json file and node_modules folder. Then do npm cache clean.

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```

And run again.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to delete your file `package-lock.json` and folder `node_modules` and then clear the npm cache by doing :

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Then :

```
npm install
npm start
```